# Non-gigabit speeds on ethernet with RTL8111/8168/8411 on EB1033 running 20.04.4

Tags: networking, ethernet, realtek, download-speed

I'm consistently getting download speeds around 40 to 60 Mbps on a RTL8111/8168/8411 chipset integrated device on an old EB1033. Upload speeds are around 40 Mbps, which is expected, but expected download speed in the network should be around 940 Mbps.

- I'm running Xubuntu 20.04.4 (ultimately, it will be a headless machine)
- kernel 5.15.0-46-generic
- the device is running with an SSD and 4GB of RAM
- I've tried multiple cat6 and cat5 cables
- I've tried the Realtek provided driver, the r8168-dkms
  package through apt, and the built-in r8169 driver, all with the same results
- using ethtool to manually set speed, duplex, or autonegotiation doesn't seem to produce any consistent difference; I'm always well under 100mbps, let alone getting to the 940 Mbps or so other ethernet devices on the network get
- setting pcie_aspm=off under GRUB doesn't produce different results (though I'm not sure the bug that caused that to be helpful to some is still present)

```
$ sudo lspci | grep RTL
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
```

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 06
       serial: 40:16:7e:0b:19:51
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.050.03-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.1.16 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:29 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:db104000-db104fff memory:db100000-db103fff
```

```
$ sudo ethtool enp2s0
Settings for enp2s0:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                         100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                         1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
    Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Link partner advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: Unknown
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
    Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                   drv probe ifdown ifup
    Link detected: yes
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: As far as I can tell at the moment, this issue now goes beyond the single device and has something to do with the ISP's local infrastructure, which would explain why none of the fixes changed behavior.